# Can we get report content in Json format using java BO sdk?

Tags: java, report, business-intelligence, business-objects-sdk

I want to retrieve the content of a BI report in Json format, Is it possible with Java BO sdk?

If so can any one give me some examples how to retrieve content in Json?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, you can't get Json natively with the SDK. You can, however export a Webi and Crystal report to XML, which you can then convert in Json.

A more complete answer would require to know which version of BO you are using, an whether you need to export WebI report, Crystal or Crystal for Enterprise reports. This will more or less dictate which SDK you will use for that, however going forward SAP is pushing hard with the RESTful services API, so that may be the one you should look to utilize.

Comment: without exporting to xml, I just want to display the content of report in xml format,Is it possible to do so? @Eric